# Glob pattern to search for the directories,files inside a directory

Tags: java

I am using a glob pattern to recursively walk through through a directory and get all the files and directories inside that directory.

I have a directory : d:/test/newfolder/...
Inside the newfolder there are some files and some directories which internally contain some files.
For Example: d:/test/newfolder/new.txt , d:/test/newfolder/temp/tempfile.doc etc..

I am using Path Mathcher to match the globpatterns.

Here is my code:

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(startDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (matcher.matches(file.getFileName())) {
                    System.out.println("found files&directories: " + file.getFileName());
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    if (matcher.matches(file.getFileName())) {
                        System.out.println("found files: " + file.getFileName());
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I want to search  for a file, i can give the pattern glob:*.txt and it works fine.

But I do not know what pattern should I give to search for directory. I want to get all the files and directories present in "newfolder" directory.

I am trying with glob:newfolder/** , but It is not working for me.

And Is there anything wrong with the code?

Please help me. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can anyone please reply to my query?

I really need an answer. It's really very urgent. :(